# Can't find bug in program (Quicksort implementation)

Tags: c++, quicksort

For some reason, whenever I try to compile the program it says "File has stopped working". It doesn't give any specific errors so I have no clue what is wrong. I've looked it over many times and can't find any errors.

This is an implementation of a quicksort algorithm.

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int pivotPos = left + rand() % right;
    int pivot = arr[pivotPos];
    int p = left;
    swap(arr[pivotPos], arr[right]);

    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[p]);
            p++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[p], arr[pivotPos]);
    return p;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex - 1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int theArr[10000];
    clock_t d1, d2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        theArr[i] = 1 + rand() % 500;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        d1 = clock();
        quickSort(theArr, 0, 10000);
        d2 = clock();

        cout << "Time: " << ((double) (d2 - d1) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, or sprinkle your code with printfs to see what's happening.

Comment: You should call quicksort with quickSort(theArr,0,9999); because you are trying to access the 'right' index.

Comment: Since you're in C++ for learning purposes I'd suggest to 1) use a debugger and 2) replace array with std::vector. It'll throw an exception when you access an **index out of range**...

Comment: where is `swap` defined?

Comment: `left + rand() % right` looks very wrong. If left is 100, right is 200, what's preventing this from evaluating to, say, 100 + 150?

Comment: Does the crash really happen when trying to compile the program, or do you mean that it crashes when you try to run it afterwards?

Comment: Is this [question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23318558/771663) related to the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

As hvd pointed out in the comments section, the following line appears wrong.

```
int pivotPos = left + rand() % right;
```

What you are looking for is:

```
int pivotPos = left + rand() % (right-left);
```

Comment: This isn't the complete answer. Abhishek Bansal rightly pointed out on the question, before my comment, that the code also accesses `arr[right]`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why do you are swapping `arr[p]` and `arr[pivotPos]` after the loop has ended.
`pivotPos` is the initial location of the pivot. The final location of the pivot will be `p-1`. At the end of the loop the array is already arranged as required. This swapping will only make the array more haphazard. And therefore, in addition to replacing

```
int pivotPos = left + rand() % right;
```

by

```
int pivotPos = left + rand() % (right - left);
```

and replacing

`arr[right]` by `arr[right-1]`

You should also replace

```
swap(arr[p], arr[pivotPos]);
return p;
```

by

```
return p-1;
```

And, since the third argument of the function `quickSort` is `<maximum index> + 1`, the recursive call

```
quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex - 1);
```

should be replaced by

```
quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex);
```